# Do you know an FOSS alternative to EtherPad or a similar service with > 8 user limit?

Tags: open-source

I'm at a summer program where about 30 students are taking collaborative notes during presentations. EtherPad works great for this but it has a limit of 8 users.

Do you know any alternatives?

Google Docs is not very robust for this kind of use (if you have used it before with more than 1 person you probably know).

Comment: I ended up contacting the etherpad people and they let us use a beta version of their product that allows more than 8 people. I highly recommend etherpad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind using a desktop application there are alternatives like [Gobby](http://gobby.0x539.de/trac/).

EDIT: [Here is a list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collaborative_real-time_editor).  While not FOSS, [Adobe Buzzword](http://www.adobe.com/acom/buzzword/) looks promising.

Answer (score 4):

EtherPad has now gone open source. You can [get the source](https://github.com/ether/pad) for it and [install it](https://github.com/ether/etherpad-lite/blob/master/README.md) on your own server now.

Answer (score 1):

http://collabedit.com